# I cannot access my websites but everyone else can

Tags: firewall, ip, blacklist

About 4 days ago I could no longer view my websites from my IP address. I can see it through proxies and other IPs, everyone else sees it fine.

I've contacted my host, they say I'm whitelisted and they can't see an issue on their end.
I called ATT and they are idiots. Bounced me around until dead ending at a voicemail.

I've tried `ipconfig /release` `ipconfig /renew` and `ipconfig /flushdns`, nada.

Tried turning off modem for 20 seconds to reset - didn't help, same IP.

I'm so confused.. even tried adding site IP to hosts file in Windows.

Anyone have a solution for this? There was something about changing the DNS in IPv4 settings but I couldn't find the right place in Win7.

**It's all sites on one particular server. Different server from same company works fine.**

Traceroute

```
  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  homeportal [192.168.1.254]
  2    30 ms    29 ms    27 ms  99-123-180-3.lightspeed.knvltn.sbcglobal.net [99
.123.180.3]
  3    28 ms    27 ms    27 ms  99.178.13.28
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6    46 ms    26 ms    27 ms  70.159.238.252
  7    31 ms    33 ms    33 ms  12.81.60.58
  8    33 ms    33 ms    31 ms  12.81.60.78
  9    32 ms    32 ms    32 ms  12.81.104.231
 10    33 ms    32 ms    33 ms  12.81.101.54
 11    36 ms    40 ms    34 ms  12.81.32.90
 12    33 ms    33 ms    33 ms  12.81.32.107
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: Can you ping the server? Can you run a traceroute?  What are the outputs?  Can you telnet to the web server port and successfully connect?

Comment: Tracert has error at 4/5 and last 10-15 hops. I'll post results.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the IP address and does ping work to your server ?

Comment: Ping gets 4 Request Timed Out

Comment: Where is your web server hosted?

Comment: Lunarpages. Other server from same host is loading fine.

Comment: Ah, LunarPages. If you typo a Port# for your Lunarpages-hosted domains even once, they'll lock you out for a half hour. I'd recommend finding another hosting company, much as I'm doing right now.

Comment: Not sure why it's closed (STACK NAZIS) ahem... but I ended up having LunarPages move my sites to a cPanel server (which immediately got the old server working as well..) ATT (ISP) was not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are hop 4 and 5 are normal for AT&T (I have them as my home ISP). Those two routers simply aren't configured to respond to ICMP.  It's annoying but not an issue.  The last IP which responds is an AT&T IP address, so that tells me that there's an AT&T router which is down, or that one of their routers was reconfigured when the problem started.

Resolving the problem will require that you talk to AT&T and have them fix the busted router or get the routing on the network to route around the problem.  In either case AT&T is the place to be talking to.

Comment: Hmm.. well maybe if I call today I'll get someone a little more specialized than their weekend crew. I'll let you know what they say.
**Do you know of an address that would let me edit router config?** Seems like these guys have it restricted.

Comment: Totally possible. It'll really depend on who you get at random if they even understand the problem that you are having.  There's not going to be any address that would let you edit their router config.

Comment: Yup, Cisco router and  you have to have some special cable and hardline the connection. They opened the firewall and 'tried everything on their end'. Transferred me to a paid tech support service but call was lost and I'm not calling back. Total loss here.